# Can I run a query over all users?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I noticed that a userid is required to run a query; but what if I want to check out a property for all users? For example, if I wanted to find the sum of upvotes for each user, not just myself? Can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

Sure. Assuming you know a bit of SQL, you can do this quite easily. For instance, [this query will select the ten users who've cast the most up-votes](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/63318/top-up-voters):

```sql
select Top 10 Id as [User Link], UpVotes from Users 
Order By UpVotes desc
```

For more tips on using Data Explorer, read [the faq](https://data.stackexchange.com/faq). For more on using SQL, see [The SO SQL Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info).